# Calculate of total length of edges in Voronoi diagram

Tags: computational-geometry

Does anyone have any suggestions how to determine the total sum of edges length in a Voronoi diagram?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Answer (score 9):

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 2}];
vm = VoronoiMesh[pts]
```

You can use the property `"EdgeLengths"`:

```
Total @ vm["EdgeLengths"]
```

> 12.2894

If you need the lengths of individual edges:

```
lengths = RegionMeasure /@ MeshPrimitives[vm, 1]
```

> {0.60034, 0.672996, 0.403197, 0.793131, 0.596543, 0.920977, 1.03974,     1.12238, 0.322772, 1.05995, 0.854316, 0.985915, 0.0806386, 0.844254,  0.264125, 1.72809}

```
Total[lengths]
```

> 12.2894

Alternatively, you can use `ArcLength` in place of `RegionMeasure`:

```
lengths == ArcLength /@ MeshPrimitives[vm, 1]
True
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it has been very helpful for me.

Comment: @MatiGer, you are most welcome.

Answer (score 8):

```
SeedRandom[1234];
R = VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 2}]];
Total[PropertyValue[{R, 1}, MeshCellMeasure]]
```

> 31.1601

Comment: I am very grateful for your response, Henrik. Thank you.

Comment: Great to hear that! You're welcome.